# How can I dynamically scale (enlarge) all GUI controls in my NetBeans Platform-based application to support accessibility?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, awt, netbeans-platform

I'm working on a **NetBeans Platform application** and want to ensure accessibility by **dynamically** scaling up the GUI components for users with visual impairments. Is there a way to achieve this programmatically for **all** GUI controls?

Primarily, I'm looking for a way to iterate through all the UI controls in the NetBeans Platform and somehow (are there setters for this?!) dynamically set the scaling in both the x and y dimensions based on the user's previous adjustment through the GUI. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could show me how to perform such an iteration and the API for setting the scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a Netbeans API for this. But it's a Java app so you can use the JDK flag `sun.java2d.uiScale`.

For example with an Ant-based NB app, your app could update file `nbproject/project.properties` with `run.args.extra=-J-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.5`

It's not truly dynamic as you need to restart the app (after user confirmation) to apply the changes, but it might be acceptable for this kind of setting.

Comment: The `java` command flag `-J-Dsun.java2d.uiScale` indeed appears to do what I need. However, I haven't figured out how to assign it programmatically (not hard-coded) to the `java` command or before the NetBeans start based on user settings. You mentioned the `nbproject/project.properties`, what is it exactly? The `nbproject` directory doesn't exist anywhere for me. Is there a NetBeans API to create it in the right place and set `run.args.extra=-J-Dsun.java2d.uiScale?`

Comment: Do you use a Maven-based or Ant-based Netbeans platform application ?

Comment: a Maven-based and IntelliJ-based (not using NetBeans IDE)

Comment: The target file to dynamically update is in etc/<your_app>.conf in the Netbeans user directory (see Places.getUserDirectory()).

Comment: Wonderful, the `etc/<your_app>.conf` is what I need to adapt. Thank you very much!